# How to integrate 2.5% sales fee in an NFT Marketplace

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, nft

I'm currenttly building an NFT marketplace, I am done with all the major functionalities, i.e listing, selling, buying etc. but the problem is, when wiriting the code earlier I used a fixed listing fee of 0.1 ether and now I would like to integrate a 2.5% fee on every sale
Here's my solidity code

```
function createMarketSale(address nftContract, uint256 itemId, uint256 commission)  
 public  
 payable  
 nonReentrant  
    {  
        uint256 price = idToMarketItem[itemId].price;  
        uint256 tokenId = idToMarketItem[itemId].tokenId;  
 require(  
 msg.value == price,  
 "Please submit the asking price in order to complete the purchase"  
        );  
        idToMarketItem[itemId].seller.transfer(msg.value);  
 IERC721(nftContract).transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, tokenId);  
        idToMarketItem[itemId].owner = payable(msg.sender);  
        idToMarketItem[itemId].sold = true;  
        _itemsSold.increment();  
 payable(owner).transfer(commission);  
    }
```

Here's How my web3 frontend interacts with the contract

```
async function buyNFT() {
 const web3Modal = new Web3Modal();
 const connection = await web3Modal.connect();
 const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection);

 const signer = provider.getSigner();
 const contract = new ethers.Contract(nftmarketaddress, Market.abi, signer);

 const price = ethers.utils.parseUnits(nft.price.toString(), "ether");
 const fee = +((2.5 / 100) * nft.price);
 let commission = fee.toString();

 let transaction = await contract.createMarketSale(nftaddress, nft.itemId, commission, {
 value: price,
 });

 await transaction.wait();
    window.location.replace("/profile");
 }
```

but I keep getting an Error: Transaction reverted: function call failed to execute when it gets to this line :

```
 payable(owner).transfer(commission);
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, please help

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @RohidasKadam https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/114948/how-to-integrate-2-5-sales-fee-in-an-nft-marketplace